# An issue with 32 bit * 32 bit data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math, int

I have this code that multiplies 32 bit * 32 bit.

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    System.Int32 x, y;
    System.Int64 z;

    System.Random rand = new System.Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        x = rand.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
        y = rand.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
        z = (x * y);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, y, z);
    }
```

However, the result is not exactly what I expected.

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overflow. The result is calculated as a 32-bit integer and after that promoted to 64 bits. To avoid that, convert the factors to 64 bits before the multiplication.

```
System.Int32 x, y;
System.Int64 z;

System.Random rand = new System.Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    x = rand.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    y = rand.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    z = ((Int64)x * y); //by casting x, we "promote" the entire expression to 64-bit.
    Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, y, z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast either x or y to `Int64` in the multiplication.  The output of the multiplication is based on the source types, not the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

Int32 * Int32 yields another Int32.  The result is overflowing.

Try:

```
System.Int64 x, y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Int32 * Int32 == Int32

you need to cast x and y to Int64 before the multiply

(Int64)Int32 * (Int64)Int32 == Int64